# Validation Spring3 + Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, spring-3

I try validate a BigDecimal field as the next:

@DecimalMin(value = "0.00", message = "message error validation")
private BigDecimal saldoFechaDefunProducto;

But I get the next error: 
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: validation failed for classes...

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: Can you provide the whole stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

you can validate like this :

```
@Digits(integer=0, fraction=2)
@Column(name = "saldoFechaDefunProducto") 
private BigDecimal saldoFechaDefunProducto;
```

and this like can help you [Hibernate Validator](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/master/annotation-processor/src/test/java/org/hibernate/validator/ap/testmodel/annotationparameters/InvalidDigitsParameters.java)

Comment: But, it validate the format, and I could set "-0,55".
I dont want negative numbers.

Comment: you can do this by @Digits(integer = -0, fraction = 55)